# Different way to form the power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The power set can be constructed as a "Cartesian product" as in the following example. Suppose $S=\{a, b, c\}$ and that $\times$ is a modified Cartesian product operator (see following paragraph), then:

$$Pset(S)=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}\boxtimes \{\emptyset,\{b\}\} \boxtimes \{\emptyset,\{c\}\}$$

The difference being that the pairs of the product are actually unified together to make one set. For example, the pair $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ yields $\emptyset$, the pair $(\emptyset, \{a\})$ yields $\{a\}$.

Does this operation have a standard name/notation? I want to prove that the resulting set is actually the power set but I need notation or try to introduce appropriate notation.

Note: This construction tells us that the cardinality is $2^{|S|}$ right away which is true.

Comment: How is what you do any different from $2^S = \{ S \to \{\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1}\}\}$?

Comment: @WillieWong That's what I'm trying to prove!

Comment: What do you mean that's what you are trying to prove? [What I wrote is a definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Representing_subsets_as_functions).

Comment: @WillieWong It's an observation. Where do they say that it's a definition?

Comment: You should probably use a symbol other than $\times$ for your *modified* Cartesian product to avoid confusion.

Comment: @RahulNarain Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe $\boxtimes$ or $\otimes$ (`\boxtimes`, `\otimes`)?

Answer (score 3):

The set you describe is not the power set of $\{a,b,c\}$. It is a set that has the same cardinality as the power set, but its elements $x$ do not satisfy $x\subseteq S$.

EDIT: after the clarifications and modifications it all makes sense now. I never saw the definition $A\boxtimes B=\{a\cup b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$, which in the context of axiomatic set theory makes sense. It does not make sense universally in naive set theory though. The equality $\mathcal P(S)=\{\emptyset ,\{s_1\}\}\boxtimes \cdots \{ \emptyset, \{s_n\}\}$ makes sense and is true when $S=\{s_1,\cdots , s_n\}$. With a bit of care it can be extended to infinite sets and infinite box products.

Comment: It is the power set! It's not the Cartesian product that's way I put it in quotes.

Comment: what makes it the power set?

Comment: Try and list all the components of the set. You can try with a set that has 1 or two elements.

Comment: if the context of the question is axiomatic set theory (say ZF) then the existence of power sets is an axiom, not a definition. If the context is naive set theory, then the power set of $S$ is the set of all subsets of $S$. What you describe is not the power set, but rather a set of the same cardinality.

Comment: The OP is using $\times$ to denote something different from the usual Cartesian product. In their notation, $A\times B=\{a\cup b:a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Comment: @Saadtaame: There is not reason to be rude or hostile, that is uncalled for.  Also, Ittay Weiss is not wrong - this is essentially the subtle difference between two objects being isomorphic rather than equal.

Comment: @EricNaslun You are right. Apologies Ittay.